# How can I discriminate between mesurement error and real change working with data expressed as percentages?

Tags: distributions

I am analizing cuantitative changes in estrogen receptor (ER) expression in paired breast cancer biopsies (biopsies of the same patients separated by time T). ER expression is measured as a percentage and can take values between 0% and 100%. RE expression is not normally distributed: in one third of biopsies the ER expression is of 0% and in two thirds its value is between 0% and 100%. When values of RE in paired biopsies (separated by time t) are compared, it can be observed that in one third of patients the differnce is of 0 percentage points(ER1=ER2), in slightly more than one third RE1 > ER2, in slightly less than one third RE1

Comment: I think to get a good answer, you'll have to be more specific about what it is you are trying to determine.  I get the feeling that you really want to know if the proportions of counts (one third, slightly more than one third, and slightly less than one third) are different from chance.  But, do you care about the one third where ER1 and ER2 are equal?  Or do you just want to compare cases where ER1>ER2 to cases where ER1<ER2?  Also, does the fact that so many are 0% need to be taken into account?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Sal. H1 = over time ER level expressed (as %) decreases. In paired biopsies we obtained ΔER = ER2-ER1,  ΔER takes values between -100 and 100%, ΣΔER <0. I assumed that if the discordance between ER1 and R2 is due to mesurement error ΔER  needs to be normally distributed. If else, there is an evolution of the tumor. Initially I used KS goodness of fit for normal distribution. However, later I thinked that as ΔER is truncated from two sides and initial distribution of ER level (ER1) is not normal, it would be inappropriate. Can I still use KS or I need another test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test against the null that ΔER = 0.  The KS test is not a good test for this.  Because there are many ways that the distribution of ΔER could be non-normal, but that don't indicate that ΔER ≠ 0.

Following are some tests to evaluate H0: ΔER = 0.  For simplicity, I'll describe these as testing ΔER.  Each of these has an analog for testing ER1 and ER2 as paired data.  Either approach is the same, as long as it is sensible to subtract e.g. ER2 – ER1.

These are just a few notes.  For whatever test you choose, be sure to understand the hypothesis being tested, and the assumptions of the test.

Also, be sure to not rely on p-values too heavily. Be sure to evaluate the effect size (proportion ER1 > ER2, etc.; median of differences; mean of differences; and so on, as appropriate). And the practical importance of the results.

One-sample sign test - Has essentially no assumptions about the distribution of data, and tests against H0: Median of differences is 0. Looks only at the count of observations where ER1>ER2 and ER1

One-sample Wilcoxon test - Is a non-parametric test.  That is, there aren't assumptions about the distribution of the underlying data.  The hypotheses tested can be a little difficult to grasp.  Usually, the H0 is written as that the data are symmetric around zero.  But note that the test is conducted on ranks. So a significant result suggests either that the ranks of differences are symmetric around a number other than zero, or are not symmetric.  This is often a good test in that it takes into account the magnitude of the differences and is a nonparametric test.

One-sample t-test - Assumes the data (differences) are normally-distributed, or the sample size is large-ish (> 30 ?) and not too skewed.  H0: the mean of the differences is 0.

Example in R

```
### At the time of writing, this code will run at:
###  https://rdrr.io/snippets/

### In this example, out of 24 observations, 
###  there are 8 ties, 6 where deltaER is negative,
###    and 10 where deltaER is positive. 

deltaER = c(  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
             -5, -5, -5,-10,-10,-15,
              5,  5,  5, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 20, 25)


hist(deltaER, col="darkgray")

barplot(table(deltaER))

#########################################################

library(DescTools)

SignTest(deltaER)

   ### One-sample Sign-Test
   ### S = 10, number of differences = 16, p-value = 0.4545
   ### alternative hypothesis: true median is not equal to 0
   ### 97.7 percent confidence interval:
   ###  0 10
   ### sample estimates:
   ### median of the differences 
   ###                        0

sum(deltaER == 0)/length(deltaER)
   ### [1] 0.3333333

sum(deltaER > 0)/length(deltaER)
   ### [1] 0.4166667

sum(deltaER < 0)/length(deltaER)
   ### [1] 0.25

########################################################

wilcox.test(deltaER)

   ### Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
   ### V = 96.5, p-value = 0.1443
   ### alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0

########################################################

t.test(deltaER)

   ### One Sample t-test
   ### t = 1.6042, df = 23, p-value = 0.1223
   ### alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
   ### 95 percent confidence interval:
   ###  -0.9651126  7.6317793
   ### sample estimates:
   ### mean of x 
   ###  3.333333

library(lsr)

cohensD(deltaER)

   ### [1] 0.327454
```

[image]
[image]